# Gecko Driver not working in C# for Firefox browser

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to run some unit tests using Selenium Webdriver and C#.Net for Firefox browser but I was unable to do it (Chrome and IE11 browsers are working smoothly).

**Here is the info I gathered:**

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

Gecko driver version: geckodriver-v0.17.0-win32

Mozilla Firefox version: 54.0.1 (32-bit)

Environment Path variable already set under "C:\LEO\SELENIUM C#\Firefox"

**Piece of Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest3
{
private IWebDriver driver;
private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
private string baseURL;

[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
    FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\LEO\SELENIUM C#\Firefox");
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
    baseURL = "http://www.dow.com";
    verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}
```

}

**Error:**

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unable to find a matching set of capabilities.
>
> TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**StackTrace:**

[image: ERROR IMAGE]
I will appreciate all your help, thanks.

Comment: Ever able to get around it ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need Firefox: Developer Edition installed and updated.

That`s should be enough in your case.

[Source with full guide.](https://www.brainbeast.best/faq-about-selenium-webdriver-on-c-sharp-with-examples/)